# Return array to method

Tags: java, arrays, return

I have a method to total up average results which calls another method which stores an array of the results but I seem to having trouble returning the array:

Array code:

```
static double findAverages() {
    double [] averagesArray = new double[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        double total = (studentMarksArray[i][0]+studentMarksArray[i][1]+studentMarksArray[i][2])/3;
        averagesArray[i] = total;
    }
    return averagesArray;
}
```

Method calling array:

```
static void highestStudentAvgMark() {
    findAverages();
    double max = averagesArray[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < averagesArray.length; i++) {
        if (averagesArray[i] > max) {
            max = averagesArray[i];
        }
    }
    findMark(max, averagesArray);
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

Comment: in your case `findAverages` returns `double` but you DONT USE IT. and its array of double but not double value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined `double` and not `double []` as return type of your method.

Also `averagesArray` is a local variable in your `findAverages()` method, so it is not visible in other methods! You need to use the return value of `findAverages()`:

```
static void highestStudentAvgMark() {
  double[] averagesArray = findAverages();
  double max = averagesArray[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < averagesArray.length; i++) {
    if (averagesArray[i] > max) {
      max = averagesArray[i];
    }
  }
  findMark(max, averagesArray);
  System.out.println(max);
}
```

Comment: That solves the error in `findAverages` but `averagesArray` is still not recognised in the `highestStudentAvgMark` method

Comment: @Colin747 You need to provide an access variable to the method call. `double[] something = findAverages();`

Comment: Thanks again, been a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature says it returns `double`, but you are returning `double[]`.

Also `findAverages();' is not stored locally, and so is not used in your second method.